# Ionic installation error!! Ubuntu

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I cannot install Ionic , i have installed `cordova 6.4.0` , my `npm 4.0.2`, `node v6.9.1`
I had Ionic installed previously , i uninstalled and now unable to install it again using `npm install -g ionic` I get this dependency error as follows:

```
 ionic2@2.0.0-rc.1
   ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.0
   ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0
   ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0
   ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0
   └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@^2.0.2

npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.2 requires a peer of typescript@^2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.3.0 requires a peer of typescript@^2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN tsickle@0.1.7 requires a peer of typescript@^2.0.0 || ^2.1.0-dev but none was installed.
```

Please someone help!!!!

Comment: when using node v6 there are lots of unexpected error occurs. please install node v5 and try again if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try installing nvm from [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).
Then run this command:

```
nvm install 5.11.0
```

Wait for the node 5.11.0 installation and then:

```
nvm use 5.11.0
```

Now, while you are using node 5.11.0 run:

```
npm i -g ionic cordova
```

This is my setup and im able to work with ionic2 RC3.